# adding spelling suggestion on HTML page

Tags: html, textarea, spelling

I am new to web development and just trying to add spelling suggestion to a `textarea`. I really don't know what I am going to need for this, need to write the code myself or use a third party library etc. Can someone suggest me how to add this functionality to a simple `HTML` page containing a  `textarea`. I want when I write a misspelled word in text area, some suggestions matching that word should appear in dropdown.

Comment: browsers enable automatically text correction on textareas

Comment: @Edorka Browser doesn't automatically correct your wrong spellings, nor it will suggest you the right one's, it will only underline the wrong one's

Comment: Right now I am testing in Mozilla but it didn't check when I entered misspelled word. Do I need to change settings in about:config?

Comment: @Mr.Alien yeah you are right, so do you have any idea what I need to do for my problem?

Comment: If you want to autocorrect, you would probably need some nice JavaScript to handle that

Comment: @aneela http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JQuery_SpellCheck_Plugin

Comment: Here's a little starting point. Maybe it helps.
http://jsfiddle.net/SNRTp/

Comment: I believe CKEditor (free Rich text editor) has a built-in "spellcheck as you type" feature: http://ckeditor.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well autocorrect in the web page can be achieved by JavaScript for sure.

There are some nice frameworks for this, probably you could see this:

https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-auto-correct

For only spellchecking (despite built-in browser checking):

http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/JQuery_SpellCheck_Plugin

Comment: how can I use these frameworks, sorry but I am a total newbie to web development and don't know how to make use out of these third party resources?

Comment: In HTML you should add something like that: <script src="<NAME OF THE JS FILE>" type="text/javascript"></script> in the HEAD section. And follow further instructions on pages I linked above. If you are not familiar with JavaScript at all I would suggest http://www.w3schools.com/js/ at the beginning